# How to get a tree of all xpaths in a website using Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, tree

### Approach I

While trying to get a hierarchical tree of all the xpaths in a website (https://startpagina.nl) using Python, I first tried to get the xpath for the branch: `/html/body` using:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://startpagina.nl'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*')
print(len(test))
driver.close()
```

and that yields a list of all elements in the website, according to the answer by @Prophet. However, I did not yet determine how to get the xpaths of these elements, nor how to sort them into a tree-like structure.

And the `/html/body/div[6]` option yields a length of 1 instead of a tree.

### Approach II

Based on the answer by @Micheal Kay, I tried to "Walk the xml" using the following Python code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree


unformatted_filename = "first.xml"
formatted_filename = "first.xml"

# Get XML from url.
resp = requests.get("https://startpagina.nl")
# resp = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
with open(unformatted_filename, "wb") as foutput:
    foutput.write(resp.content)

# Improve XML formatting
with open(unformatted_filename) as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "xml")
    print(f"soup={soup}")
    with open(formatted_filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(soup.prettify())


# Parse XML
tree = ET.parse(formatted_filename, parser=ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8"))
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    child.tag, child.attrib

tree = ET.parse(formatted_filename)
for elem in tree.getiterator():
    if elem.tag:
        print("my name:")
        print("\t" + elem.tag)
    if elem.text:
        print("my text:")
        print("\t" + (elem.text).strip())
    if elem.attrib.items():
        print("my attributes:")
        for key, value in elem.attrib.items():
            print("\t" + "\t" + key + " : " + value)
    if list(elem):  # use elem.getchildren() for python2.6 or before
        print("my no of child: %d" % len(list(elem)))
    else:
        print("No child")
    if elem.tail:
        print("my tail:")
        print("\t" + "%s" % elem.tail.strip())
    print("$$$$$$$$$$")
```

However, I did not yet determine how to get the xpaths of the respective elements.

### Question

Hence, I would like to ask:

*How does one get a tree of all the xpaths in website, using Python?*
(And I wondered whether this tree will be cyclic or not, though I expect I will find out once I know how to get the Tree.).

### Expected Output

Based on manually going through the HTML:
[image]
I would expect the output to look something like this:

```
| /html

|-- //*[@id="browser-upgrade-notification"]

|-- //*[@id="app"]

|-- /html/head

|-- /html/body
|--/-- /html/body/noscript
|--/-- /html/body/div[2]

|--/-- /html/body/header/section
|--/--/-- /html/body/header/section/div
|--/--/--/-- /html/body/header/section/div/div[1]
....
```

This would be an example of the list of tree.

Comment: Can you include an example of the desired output?

Comment: Yes, I have included an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

The total number of XPaths that select one or more elements is infinite (for example it will include paths like `/a/b/../b/../b/../b`), but if you restrict yourself to paths of the form `/a[i]/b[j]/c[k]` then the number of paths is equal to the number of elements, and the "tree" of XPaths is isomorphic with the original XML tree.

If you want the distinct paths without a numerical predicate, for example `/a/b/c`, `/a/b/d`, then the simplest approach is probably to walk the XML document, get the path for each element (in this form) and eliminate duplicates. If rather than a flat list of paths you want a tree structure, then build it up as you go using nested maps/dictionaries.

The reason it complains about `/html/body/` is that a legal XPath expression cannot contain a trailing `/`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I am experiencing some difficulties walking the xml. In particular I don't get any `/html/body/div/..` elements in approach II. Would you happen to have an example for reference?

Answer (score 1):

- `/html/body/` is not a valid XPath, `/html/body` can be used instead.
- `/html/body/div[6]` is matching a single element on that page while `/html/body/div[6]/*` matches 3 elements.
- `//*` will return you all the elements on the page.
- Anyway, `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` returns a list of **web elements** matching the passed XPath locator. This will not give you XPaths of the nodes on the page.
  This method **receives** XPath as a parameter and **returns** a list of web elements.